# R How to tell a (t-test) function the needed column in an indirect way?

Tags: r, indexing, placeholder

This is the data with the two columns 'weight' and 'group':

```
genderweight <- structure(list(weight = c(95.0626365041014, 65.9189881179415, 
64.1289176345525, 66.1688823533661, 81.6245374434498, 85.1845386418439, 
81.0348729928744, 92.161156464954, 86.3842380662202, 64.8582493776221, 
62.3256566394621, 85.0980797936812, 80.0399859200671, 83.3698935236987, 
62.8710960018134, 77.0097819307823, 62.9067362884316, 62.8505200797307, 
62.2199243419118, 86.2430806667288, 83.8522826935738, 59.3086045947413, 
82.578094058482, 62.9779809883867), group = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Package and library needed:

```
install.packages("rstatix")
library(rstatix)
```

I would like to use a placeholder in the following function:

```
t_test(genderweight, weight ~ group, detailed = TRUE)
```

My placeholder could be named i, for example, and afterwards I would like to run:

```
i <- "weight"

t_test(genderweight, i ~ group, detailed = TRUE)
```

Or alternatively, `i` could be a number, e.g. `i = 1` and then I would like to run:

```
t_test(genderweight,genderweight[,i] ~ group, detailed = TRUE)
```

For both ways, I get an error message of the following type:

```
Error in `vec_as_location2_result()`:
! Can't extract columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `genderweight[, 1]` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Is there a way to tell the function in an indirect way which column you want for the t-test?

Comment: Rewrite `i ~ group` as `as.formula(paste(i, "~ group"))` and pass your function a character string containing the name of the column you wish to analyse.  Does that work?

Comment: Try `get(i)`...

Comment: @ Limey: Thank you very much, your solution worked! Don't you want to post it as an answer so I can mark the question as solved?
@ Rui Barradas: Thank you, too! Unfortunately, get(i) didn't work. Maybe something is needed in addition?